# Java Maven 3.0.4 Obscene memory consumptions

Tags: java, maven

I am working with a multi-module maven project (~100) modules, modules within modules etc...
From certain point it has become unbelievably memory hungry when celan installing the project, no test skipping just

> mvn clean install

So without 3GB allocated to permgen - it cannot complete those goals successfully which is insane by my POV because whole project with compiled source presented in standard target directory + metadata doesn't weigh more than 1GB ~980MB.

I have some experience of profiling heap memory and its dumps but I never have dealt with profiling PermGen and Maven plus its plugins so after googling for a while all I ever found concerning maven 3 and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space which occurs is to increase PermGen space but never have I found how to try and solve the problem -
Maybe some MAVEN plugin, maybe malformed pom structure miss configuration etc...

I would really like to hear out suggestions concerning my problem and the action option that are available in this situation.

Thank you

Comment: I have worked with several huge (150-200 modules) maven projects, and I have never needed more than 256MB PermGen. Just to be on the safe side, did you try maven 3.0.5 (I don't think it will make a difference). Does the same happen when skipping tests?

Comment: Have you done a memory dump to just quickly see what Objects it is filled up with? This may help to figure out who is the culprit.

Comment: have you tried to make heap dumps with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and examine it? Can you also list your MAVEN_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS

Comment: Also: try running up to a lower phase (compile, test, generate-sources) and see if the problem persists. Try building only partitions of your project. Either it is a plugin running wild (any custom plugins?) or a specific project.

Comment: Switching to JDK8 (No more permgen) could solve your problem.

Comment: @blackbuild - disabling tests helps and we use 1C fork option in Surfire plugin. I will try your propositions concerning lower phases. At some point there were specific modules that whacked out but only in the grand scheme of things, installing it separately did not result in OutOfmemory. And as to higher maven version - seems everything gets only worse. Intellijj idea dependency resolving goes off the rocker for 4 hours if I use "Import Using Maven 3" option instead of 15 seconds tops.

Comment: @JulienS. One does not simply switch JDK major version in a project of such magnitude as chances always will be there are proprietary frameworks tied in with JDK 1.6 - yes forgot to mention JDK version.

Comment: @Xeperis Since you fork in surefire, it could (should?) not be the culprit. Do you use failfast-plugin, or some generation? In the past occasionally hat problems using xtext generation (now generation forks its own jvm, so the problem does not occur anymore). Perhaps you could include a list of used plugins in your question.

Comment: what happens if you skip the tests? could be mem leak in a 3rd party plugin. Do you have the time to build separately each module and see which ones are with highest mem consumption? Do you remember what was last added before the build process started consuming this much memory?

Comment: you could also do some "poor-mans-profiling". Enter gmaven or antrun plugin in specific phases of your poms which just print out permgen usage.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, when I will get around to it I shall see. Main difference was moving to maven 3. Tracking changes would be difficult as our ROOT pom has it's parent pom which is entire another department working on 100+ module application which basically we extend with our own 100+ module project. So basically lot of transitive stuff gets included when upgrading framework version. But still thank you for your thoughts and suggestions.